# Emploi de "tous" avec "on"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Peut-on dire la phrase suivante:

> Ne t'inquiète pas - on a **tous** des moments difficiles.

ou devrait-on utiliser plutôt **tout**?

Si c'est

> ... nous avons **tous** des moments difficiles.

il n'y a aucun doute.

Comment: *Tous* is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'accord avec le pronom *on* quand il sert de première personne du pluriel (la forme familière de *nous*) est un peu bizarre. Le verbe principal est toujours à la troisième personne du singulier (accord grammatical). S'il y a un participe ou un adjectif qui s'accorderait, il est en général au singulier, mais on trouve de plus en plus le pluriel. Les compléments moins directement attachés au verbe sont au pluriel (accord sémantique).

> [On ***est*** [sing.] arrivé***(s)*** [sing., quelquefois plur.]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+arriv%C3%A9%2C+on+est+arriv%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20arriv%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0) au but.
>   [On n'***est*** [sing.] pas sorti***(s)*** [sing., quelquefois plur.]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+n%27est+pas+sorti%2Con+n%27est+pas+sortis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20n%27est%20pas%20sorti%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20n%27est%20pas%20sortis%3B%2Cc0)¹ de l'auberge.
>   [On ***est*** [3<sup>e</sup> sing.] bon***(s)*** [sing.] pour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+est+bon+pour%2Con+est+bons+pour&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20est%20bon%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20est%20bons%20pour%3B%2Cc0) se faire saucer².
>   On ***est*** [3<sup>e</sup> sing.] ***les*** meilleur***s*** [plur.] des moments difficiles.
>   On ***a*** [3<sup>e</sup> sing.] tou***s*** [plur.].

Pour les cas ambigus, avec un adjectif, j'ai l'impression on a plus tendance à mettre l'adjectif au pluriel quand il est féminin, peut-être parce qu'il y a déjà un accord sémantique à faire : « on est bon**nes** pour … », « on n'est pas soumi**ses** », etc. Pour le pronom *tous*, le pluriel est obligatoire (on peut dire « tout le groupe » au singulier, mais ce n'est pas employé lorsque le concept de groupe n'est pas explicite et mis en avant) : « on a tou**s** … », « on a tou**tes** … ».

Comme il s'agit d'une tournure orale, l'écrit devrait suivre l'oral. Même si l'usage dominant à l'écrit est le singulier (influencé par l'accord grammatical classique), la langue demande le pluriel, et on devrait transcrire cette tournure orale systématiquement avec un pluriel.

¹  <sub>À cause d'un bug de Ngram Viewer, il faut re-cliquer sur « Search » pour voir le graphe.</sub> 
²  <sub>Se faire saucer (familier) = se prendre la pluie.</sub>

Comment: Nice. Another possible influence on the choice of *tous* could be that *tout* in this sense, as George implies, would be paradoxical with any other of the other grammatically singular pronouns since they're also semantically singular. By force of analogy it could be ruled out (particularly, as you mention, since the distinction would be heard orally -- that is, [tu] can't have this meaning with any other subject).

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi dans ton deuxième exemple, tu précises "quelques fois plur." pour le verbe. *"On sont pas sortis"* ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Erreur de couper-coller, corrigée, merci.

Answer (score 2):

Tous bien sur!
You're saying 'we all have difficult times', not ' we have whole difficult times'

Answer (score 2):

Je me réfère à l'excellente explication grammaticale de Gilles, pour prendre une autre approche qui est celle du style (autrement dit, distinguer entre ce qui est interdit/permis et ce qui serait judicieux).

Bien que "on" ait désormais tendance a remplacer la première personne du pluriel et que cela soit grammaticalement admis, il faut quand même se rappeler qu'il s'agit à la base d'une troisième personne du singulier, qui a pris un sens indéterminé. [Le TLFi fait le tour de la question](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/on). Selon le même TLFi, il est dérivé du latin *homo*, "un homme".

J'aurais donc tendance à systématiquement utiliser "nous" quand il s'agit de personnes **déterminées**, en tout cas à l'écrit:

> Nous sommes arrivés au but.

Je ne trouve pas choquant de dire:

> On a tous des moments difficiles.

Vu qu'il s'agit d'une généralisation à toute la société ("tous" est là pour indiquer que la règle est toujours applicable).

Alors que la phrase:

> Nous avons tous des moments difficiles.

serait plus judicieuse quand elle s'applique un ensemble précis de personnes (par exemple pour une équipe sportive, une entreprise, etc.)

En revanche, lorsqu'il est important d'être un peu plus formel, particulièrement à l'écrit:

> **Tout le monde a** des moments difficiles.

S'agissant d'une question de style, je laisse ce qui précède à l'appréciation de chacun.