# Emploi de "nous" avec "on"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pluriel, pronoms-réfléchis

Dans cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25816/emploi-de-tous-avec-on), on a  constaté que les formes plurielles *tous* et *toutes* sont celles qu’on devrait utiliser avec le pronom *on*, plutôt que les formes singulières *tout* et *toute*.

> On a **tous** ...
>
> On a **toutes** ...

Et si on utilise le pronom *on* d’une manière réflexive ?

> On ne peut pas ___ plaindre.

Peut-on remplir le blanc avec *nous*, ou la seule réponse correcte est-elle *se* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux réponses sont possibles mais avec des sens différents.

> 1 : On ne peut pas se plaindre.

Le plus courant est la réponse attendue. C'est l'expression idiomatique qui signifie « notre situation fait que nous n'avons pas de raison d'exprimer des regrets, un mécontentement, etc. ». Cette phrase peut aussi signifier, plus rarement : « nous n'avons pas le droit ou la possibilité de nous plaindre » :

> 2 : On ne peut pas nous plaindre.

L'autre forme est un peu tirée par les cheveux. Elle signifie « ils ne peuvent pas nous plaindre », c'est à dire, « les autres n'ont pas de raison d'exprimer de la compassion envers nous ». Comme la première phrase, le sens « nous n'avons pas le droit ou la possibilité de nous plaindre » est ici aussi possible en français très relâché :

Comment: *“nous n'avons pas le droit ou la possibilité de nous plaindre”* est repris exactement pareil à lui-même pour chacun des deux choix de mots. Afin de les distinguer, il serait bien que le second soit reformulé (je verrais assez votre expression de compassion réutilisée aussi pour le second cas).

Comment: @Feelew J'ai repris exactement la même formulation car je ne perçois pas de différence de sens significative dans ce cas précis. (On ne peut pas se plaindre au directeur **=** On ne peut pas nous plaindre au directeur)

Comment: J'y perçois une différence. Le premier cas traité est réflexif, **on** parle de soi-même. Le second indique un sentiment de compassion dont l'expression serait clairement appliquée à **nous** différent du **on** l'exprimant.

Comment: @Feelew Je ne vois pas de compassion dans le deuxième exemple et le prends juste comme une variante en français relâché de « Nous ne pouvons pas nous plaindre au directeur ».

Comment: Je me suis sans doute mal exprimé. _“On ne peut pas nous plaindre”_ pour moi peut signifier que: 1) les autres n'ont pas de raison particulière d'exprimer de la compassion envers nous, notre situation n'est pas mauvaise; **ou** 2) les autres n'ont pas le droit ou la possibilité d'exprimer la compassion qu'ils pourraient ressentir envers nous. Une analyse de **on=nous** dans cette phrase me semble très peu naturelle...

Comment: OK! J'avais mal compris votre dernière intervention. Vous posez donc ***on=nous*** dans la dernière version. Je vous concède que ça pourrait être employé dans une langue très relâchée. Mon expérience ne m'a simplement pas exposé à ce genre de tournure.